# Default arguments in functions which defined in object

Tags: javascript

Here is my code:

```
MyModel =  {
  get: function(key, model) {
    if(typeof(model) === 'undefined') {   // A
      model = Model.get();                // A
    }                                     // A
    return model.data[key];
  },
  getAll: function(model) {
    if(typeof(model) === 'undefined') {
      model = Model.get();
    }
    return model.data;
  },
  save: function(data, model) {
    if(typeof(model) === 'undefined') {
      model = Model.get();
    }
    model.save(data);
  },
  //...
}
```

The `A` part repeats.

Is there a way to do it more beautiful?

Something like `get: function(key, model = Model.get())`;

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters), but it does not work in many browsers.

```
function setBackgroundColor(element, color = 'rosybrown') {
  element.style.backgroundColor = color;
 }

setBackgroundColor(someDiv);            // color set to 'rosybrown'
setBackgroundColor(someDiv, undefined); // color set to 'rosybrown' too
setBackgroundColor(someDiv, 'blue');    // color set to 'blue'
```

Comment: Check the warning in a green block on the page you're referring to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make it a function in your object, thus keeping your code dry

```
getModel: function(model){
   return model || Model.get();
}
```

Now use the following in the blocks where you need the model.

```
var test_model = this.getModel(model);
```

Answer (score 0):

Default Parameters are a part of ECMA 6 proposal and only work on Firefox 15.0 and up. No other browsers support it.

Comment: Even though you're precisely correct, it does not address the question asked.